# Log4cplus DailyRollingFileAppender MaxBackupIndex clarification

Tags: logging, configuration, log4cplus

I am struggling to understand the purpose and meaning of DailyRollingFileAppender MaxBackupIndex property in the Log4cplus configuration file.
As explained in the API documentation:

"This property limits how many backup files are kept per single logging period; e.g. how many log.2009-11-07.1, log.2009-11-07.2 etc. files are kept."

So, if I have the following configuration, where DailyRollingFileAppender scheduled as DAILY:

```
    log4cplus.rootLogger = INFO, logfile
    log4cplus.appender.logfile = log4cplus::DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4cplus.appender.logfile.File = /myLogFile.log
    log4cplus.appender.logfile.Schedule = DAILY
    log4cplus.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex = 10
    log4cplus.appender.logfile.Append = true
    log4cplus.appender.logfile.ImmediateFlush = true
```

I expect that on every new day, a new log file is created with the new date. for example:

log.2018-03-07, 
log.2018-03-08, 
log.2018-03-09,

What I can't seem to understand is WHEN do these backup files are created, and what do they contain?

Answer (score 0):

The file can roll over if you close the appender. This is historical behaviour. You can also try [`TimeBasedRollingFileAppender`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1TimeBasedRollingFileAppender.html) which has a behaviour more in line with what most people expect.

Comment: I tried using TimeBasedRollingFileAppender with schedule property of "MINUTELY", but there was no creation of new log files every minute, as the DailyRollingFileAppender does. why is that?

Comment: I got it.  TimeBasedRollingAppender schedules through it's filenamepattern property.